# Can you define a function in GAS without actually calling it when it is being defined?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running the following code and was expecting it to create a pdf in the relevant location. I have tested this ExportSpreadsheet function on its own and it worked fine, but when it is brought in to this program, it does not fire. In the Executions log, it says the function is not defined (see image below).

I am new to GAS, but is there a way to define a function without actually calling it?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1")

//Set active cell to A2 (cell below Name header) when file is opened.
function onOpen() {
  sheet1.getRange('A2').activate();
}

//Look for name from scanner
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  if (range.getA1Notation() === 'A2') {
    var active = ['Alpha', 'Beta'].includes(range.getValue()) ? "D2" : "A2";  //D2 for correct responses, A2 for incorrect (repeats the process)
    sheet1.getRange(active).activate();
  }


  //Does this cell contain a valid part number?
  var values = sheet1.getRange('D2:D27').getValues();
  for(var i in values){
    if(values[i][0].match("PLA-OPTRET1-")!=null){ //Retainer Element 1
     //cell contains "PLA-OPTRET1-". Do something
      range.offset(0,1).activate();  //In the Quantity column
    } 
    
    if(values[i][0].match("PLA-OPT1-")!=null){  //Element 1
     //cell contains "PLA-OPT1-". Do something 
      range.offset(0,1).activate();
    }
  


    if(values[i][0].match("Done")!=null){
      function ExportSheet()  {
      const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
      var invMoves = SpreadsheetApp.openById('GenericSpreadsheetID').getSheetByName("GenericSheetName");
      var lastbatch = invMoves.getValue('F2');

      let inventoryTransaction = DriveApp.getFileById('GenericSpreadsheetId');

      let blob = inventoryTransaction.getAs('application/pdf');
      let pdf = DriveApp.getFolderById('NameOfPDFCreated')
        .createFile(blob)
        .setName(`Batch ${lastbatch} - Inventory Transaction ${date}`);
      }
      ExportSheet();
      sheet1.getRange('F12').activate();

    }

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In regards to your error, it's saying `SpreadsheetApp.spreadsheetId()` is not a function because it doesn't actually exist. You're looking for [SpreadsheetApp.openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid).

In regards to your question, functions are not called when they are defined in this manner. Your call happens at `ExportSheet();` after you've defined the function.

Comment: You are correct on the error issue. The disconnect is that I got the "not a function" error the last time I ran it and just assumed it was the same error.

Just to be sure I am using the correct way to open the spreadsheet, I am only wanting to read information from one of those cells, not actually have it open. Is the openByID still the correct function to use there?

And with the function call, should I just define the function up top with my variable definitions then call it later? I tried this earlier and it prevented my onOpen() function from triggering.

Comment: If the Sheets file you are trying to fetch values is the same as the active one (`ss` variable), you can instead use the variable `ss`, which is defined in a global context. If you want to fetch values from another Sheet file, then you may use `openById()`. In regards to your other question, yes, you can define the `ExportSheet` function at the same level as `onOpen` and `onEdit` and just call it when necessary.

Comment: @Gustavo Thank you for the clarification. I am now getting an error saying I don't have the proper permissions to access this. I have tried opening the json file and adding the "oauthScopes" and the relevant permission, but it doesn't want to save. Any thoughts?

Comment: @bjw Try creating a new function with the contents of your onEdit code, and set it to trigger "on edit".

Comment: @bjw If you perform any operations that require user authentication within a `Simple Trigger` function (onEdit in this case), then you must use an `Installable Trigger` instead as @NEWAZA suggested. More information on trigger restrictions can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)